# Google Drive API v3 download google spreadsheet as Excel

Tags: python, google-drive-api, google-api-python-client

I try to download a Google Drive spreadsheet as an Excel file. As far as I can tell, the Google Drive API should make this very simple by just specifying a different mime type to the [export_media](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-downloads) request.

Based on the tutorial script I can **successfully** download the spreadsheet as CVS and Open Office sheet. Great!

However with the mime type set to `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet` - as specified for MS Excel the downloader continues to read from the stream without ever stopping and without increasing the status progress.

The full script is [here](https://pastebin.com/ynmBTzFD). To run, follow the instructions to create an app in the Google Drive API docs [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/python)

The offending code is here:

```
    file_id = 'my spreadsheet id'

    request = service.files().export_media(fileId=file_id, mimeType='application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet')

    fh = FileIO('data.xls', 'wb')
    downloader = MediaIoBaseDownload(fh, request)
    done = False
    while done is False:
        status, done = downloader.next_chunk()
        print("Download %d%%." % int(status.progress() * 100))
```

It continues to print `Download 0%` and never stops.

Comment: Is this the same behavior when you test across different machines?

Comment: Hi @AL. I don't know, to be honest. I only have one at hand. I could try running it in a container. If you are willing - maybe you could run it on your machine? Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out that the `MediaBaseIODownload` relies on 'content-range`or`content-length` being present to know when to stop.

```
  if 'content-range' in resp:
    content_range = resp['content-range']
    length = content_range.rsplit('/', 1)[1]
    self._total_size = int(length)
  elif 'content-length' in resp:
    self._total_size = int(resp['content-length'])
```

However, in a debugger I can see, they are not present in the response. Hence, it cannot not know when being done.

```
  if self._progress == self._total_size:
    self._done = True
```

The solution was to not run a partial download but to download in full:

```
request = service.files().export_media(fileId=file_id, mimeType='application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet')
with open('data.xlsx', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(request.execute())
```